# Modify Spring MVC Request to List Parameter Binding to Not Separate on Commas

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc

I am sending `names` from a simple web form:

```
<form action="test" method="GET">
  <select name="names" multiple="true">
    <option>Doe, Jane</option>
    <option>Doe, John</option>
  </select>
  <input type="submit"/>
</form>
```

The `names` are bound to a `List` in the controller:

```
@GetMapping("/test")
public String test(@RequestParam List<String> names, Model m) {
  System.out.println(names.size());
  System.out.println(names);
  return "test";
}
```

But because my name values contain a comma (`,`) Spring is parsing what should be a single name value into two Strings.

The `GET` request for `/test?names=Doe, John` (removing url encoding of the comma from `,` to `%2C` for readability) results in a list containing two String values, `Doe` and `John` rather than the single value `Doe, John` as I'd like.

However, things work as expected when sending multiple values like: `/test?names=Doe, Jane&names=Doe, John`.  In this case I have a list with two items: `Doe, Jane` and `Doe, John`.

One workaround is to simply always send an empty `names` value in the form by including:

```
<input type="hidden" name="names"/>
```

And then removing the empty value from the list.  But I'd like not to have to do this.

How can I configure Spring MVC to NOT parse string values using a comma but instead expect list attribute values to simply repeat like `?name=Jon&name=Sue&name=Bob`?

I'm using Spring Boot 2.3.2.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The conversion seems to happen in:

`org.springframework.core.convert.support.StringToCollectionConverter`

which must be a defult converter registered by the framework.

You can use an `@InitBinder` method in a controller or a Controller Advice to register converters however I am not sure how you override or disable this default converter.

The simplest thing to do then is just to fall back to accessing the param directly from the HttpServletRequest:

```
 @Controller
public class TestController {

    @RequestMapping("/test")
    public String test(@RequestParam("names") List<String> names, HttpServletRequest request) {
        
        //1
        System.out.println(request.getParameterValues("names").length);
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(request.getParameterValues("names")));
        
        //2
        System.out.println(names.size());
        System.out.println(names);

        return null;
    }
}
```

After additional experimentation, you can disable the invocation of the framework's `StringToCollectionConverter` in Spring Boot by explicitly removing the conversion from `String.class` to `Collection.class` from the `GenericConversionService`:

```
@Autowired
void conversionService(GenericConversionService genericConversionService) {
  List<String> names = genericConversionService.convert("Ed, Al", List.class);
  System.out.println(names.size()); // 2

  genericConversionService.removeConvertible(String.class, Collection.class);

  names = genericConversionService.convert("Ed, Al", List.class);
  System.out.println(names.size()); // 1

}
```